# How to start AVAudioPlayer without loading full buffer?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avaudioplayer, foundation

I want to use the `AVAudioPlayer` to play a previously recorded file. That recording works fine, and I saved the file to the temp directory.

The problem is, as soon as I setup the `AVAudioPlayer`, it starts buffering and `will not start playing before fully buffering` that recording. Now it may work fine with recordings of about 30 seconds, but I also want it to work with like 1 hour long recordings. I am talking about > 1 minute of waiting.

**How do I force AVAudioPlayer to just begin playing with the current buffer?**
Like I can tell `AVPlayer` with `player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false`
because I don't expect there to be any stalling issue.

**Or how do I get something like averagePower()->Float from AVPlayer?**
I could not use `AVPlayer` because I need something like `AVAudioPlayer`'s `func averagePower(forChannel channelNumber: Int) -> Float` to show a visualized presentation of the recording. If you know how to get to those averagePower values from AVPlayer, -Item, -Asset or -Track, that would be fine too, I could not find anything fitting.

Comment: You need to use Core Audio for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, if you use `AVAudioPlayer` but call **`player.play() on another thread`**, it is not waiting for the buffer and starts playing right away.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    self.player.play()
}
```

But this comes with some restrictions, because now I **can't use player.play(at: TimeInverval)** because that seems to interrupt building the buffer and then the file will not be played to its full duration. **I worked around that by setting player.currentTime** before player.play(), which does not to bother the buffer.